# List all Wikipedia articles in one category and subcategories

Tags: php, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

Is there any way to get a list of all Wikipedia articles in one category, including all subcategories?

I tried to extract the links from the category page with a PHP script, but it seems like there is no possibility to get all articles including subcategories.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried to extract the links of the all articles page with a php script, but it seems like there is no possibility to get all articles including subcategories.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect that. It doesn't seem programming-related at all right now.

Comment: this one creates a list of all pages / subcategory-pages and prints them out as pdf-file: https://github.com/produnis/myscripts/blob/master/PHP/mwc2pdf.php    You might want to just skip the printing-part...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using the [MediaWiki API](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), specifically [`list=categorymembers`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers).

Here's a random example:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Defunct_airports_in_Prince_Edward_Island

The link above will give you a list of all pages in [Category:Defunct airports in Prince Edward Island](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDefunct_airports_in_Prince_Edward_Island) in XML format (pretty-printed for easier human readability by default).  You can choose from a variety of machine-readable [output formats](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aData_formats#Output) by appending an appropriate parameter, such as `format=xml` or `format=json`, to the URL.

Note that, in general, the query shown above will include *all* pages in the category, including both articles and subcategories.  You can limit it to articles only by including the parameter `cmnamespace=0`, but then you'll miss any subcategories.  (You can always get those separately with `cmnamespace=14`, though.)

The reason you might want that information is that the `list=categorymembers` query by itself will *not* recurse into subcategories, so if you want that, you'll have to do it yourself.  If you do that, though, be careful not to get caught in any category loops, and make sure you do a sanity check on the results — it's very easy to get *way* more pages than you expected from a full subcategory traversal.

Also, by default, a single `categorymembers` query will give you at most 10 results.  You can increase that limit to 500 (or 5000, if you happen to have access to a [bot-flagged account](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBots) on Wikipedia) by including the parameter `cmlimit=max` in your query, but even then, very large categories might get cut off.  If that happens, the query result will include a [query continuation](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aGenerator#Continuing_queries) section that will tell you (or your [MW API client library](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCreating_a_bot#PHPde)) how to obtain the rest of the pages using additional queries.

---

**Edit:** I kind of missed the fact that you were specifically asking about getting articles in subcategories.  Here's some basic (untested!) example code on how you could do that using the [Apibot 0.40](http://apibot.zavinagi.org/index.php/Apibot_0.40) bridge interface (which I just picked randomly, because it looked like a decent PHP MW API client library, so that I wouldn't need to worry about details like query continuations):

```php
function pages_under_category ( $category ) {
    global $bridge;  // I'll assume you've set this up in advance

    $queue = array( $category );  // categories to fetch
    $seen  = array( $category );  // categories already seen
    $pages = array();  // result pages (format: $title => array( $cat, ... ))

    while ( !empty( $queue ) ) {
        $cat = array_shift( $queue );

        $query = $bridge->query_list_categorymembers();
        $query->title = $cat;  // assume "Category:" prefix is included

        // fetch the contents of the category
        $query_result = $query->xfer();
        while ( $query_result ) {
            foreach ( $query->data as $page_data ) {

                $title = $page_data['title'];
                $namespace = $page_data['ns'];

                if ( $namespace == 0 ) {      // it's an article!
                    if ( !isset( $pages[$title] ) ) {
                        $pages[$title] = array();
                    }
                    $pages[$title][] = $cat;  // record where we found it
                }
                else if ( $namespace == 14 ) {  // it's a subcategory
                    if ( !in_array( $title, $seen ) ) {
                        $seen[] = $title;  // avoid loops!
                        $queue[] = $title;
                    }
                }
            }
            $query_result = $query->next();
        }
    }
    return $pages;
}
```

One feature you might want to add to the code above is some kind of limit on the result size / number of iterations, so that even if the recursive retrieval somehow finds its way to, say, [Category:Contents](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aContents), it will at some point stop trying to list every page on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to test it within the next week.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with PetScan, look e.g. at the example https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=19820

You can choose how deep you go into subcategories and add esarch terms and/or exclude pages belonging to specified other categories.